# Create a dynamic database connection in Airflow DAG

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am using Apache-Airflow 2.2.3 and I know we can create connections via **admin/connections**. But I trying for a way to create a connection using dynamic DB server details.

My DB host, user, password details are coming through the DAGRun input config and I need to read and write the data to DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read connection details from the DAGRun config:

```py
# Say we gave input {"username": "foo", "password": "bar"}

from airflow.models.connection import Connection

def mytask(**context):
    username = context["dag_run"].conf["username"]
    password = context["dag_run"].conf["password"]
    connection = Connection(login=username, password=password)
```

However, all operators (that require a connection) in Airflow take an argument `conn_id` that takes a string identifying the connection in the metastore/env var/secrets backend. At the moment it is not possible to provide a Connection object.

Therefore, if you implement your own Python functions (and use the PythonOperator or `@task` decorator) or implement your own operators, you should be able to create a Connection object and perform whatever logic using that. But using any other existing operators in Airflow will not be possible.

Comment: Thanks. I will use session.add(conn) and session.commit() to store connections to backend DB.